# How can we reduce the amount of energy consumed by a large number of electrical motors in a factory?

Tags: energy

if we suppose we have an electrical installation in which we have 1000 motors, and we want to reduce the amount of energy consumed by those motors.
where can we start and what do we need to do ?
what are the things to focus on ?
and what are some solutions we can give in order to reduce the amount of energy consumed by a particular motor ?
what are some problems that need to fixed while the motor is operating and that can result in consumption reduction if they are eliminated ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Get an industrial power consultant. You will often see, on the outside of buildings with a lot of big motors and other inductive loads, a fenced off area where the power enters the structure. In the cage are huge capacitors that are used to "balance the load". These will drastically reduce power costs and/or make the power company a lot happier.

Comment: Is this possibly a homework question? I'm certain there are lots of articles on increasing efficiency, eliminating waste power and so on you could research on the net.

Comment: Friction. Make sure the motor and the machinery it's driving are in good alignment and well-lubricated. Also, if a motor is grossly over-rated for the load it's driving it will have a poor power factor, so there might be some opportunity to reevaluate that.

Comment: thank you guys for answering, that's indeed a project i have to work on in my internship, i have to come up with a plan to reduce the amount of energy consumed by the motors in the factory by 1MW to 1.5MW.
that's why i'm posting this question here to get some guidance to know which way to proceed in order to get this right.

Comment: You are hoping to improve the consumption from 2.5MW to 1.5MW, 60% reduction? what's your budget?  Is it a real "this has to be done" or one of those graduate,internship theorycraft things?  I had todo a small paper on reduction of consumption at university and the aim was to drive home motor-drives, even for air conditioning to reduce consumption

Comment: I could be wrong, but don't electric motors produce a large imbalance in real versus reactive power? Given that a reduction in energy consumed is in part an effort for efficiency and cost, I would think a reduction in the reactive power load would go a long way in helping.

Comment: @JonRB the aim is to reduce the consumption of motors which is about 17MW to 16MW or 15.5MW, it's a real study which, if convincing and strong enough, will be implemented in the factory in order to reduce its overall energy consumption of all the motors (induction motors, pumps, compressors, etc). Since you've already worked on the reduction of energy consumption of motors, if you can help me here, please don't hesitate on guiding me to work in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

This is a mechanical problem, not a electrical one.  Any one motor is going to have the efficiency it has, so either use the mechanical power out of the motor more efficiently or use more efficient motors.

One thing you can do to reduce cost, which is not the same as reducing power usage, is to regulate your power factor.  Large industrial electricity customers are charged not just for the energy they consume, but also by the power factor.  This is because a low power factor causes more waste and stresses on equipment for the electric company for the same power you consume.

Most electric loads look inductive, and a bunch of motors certainly so.  There are various ways of raising your power factor.  For example, one old but tried and true scheme is to switch in banks of capacitors as needed to cancel the inductive part of your load.  In the old days there would be a meter and a bunch of big knife switches, and somebody who's job it was keep the system tweaked.  Nowadays this is done more automatically.

There are various options.  Since this is for a large commercial installation, you really should hire someone that specializes in this sort of thing.  Don't be penny-wise and pound-foolish.  Get the right professional to do this right.

### Added:

You now tell us you are a intern that has been tasked to look into this and reduce overall power consumption by 1 to 1.5 MW.

Ug.  You have been put into a bad position and are in over your head unless there is someone more senior around you can work with.  If your job is to help out the senior person with the grunt tasks, great, dig in and learn a lot.  However, if the company is trying to cheap out by getting a intern to do a real experienced engineer's job, then you and they are headed for trouble and you need to get out of there and find a better internship.

Even at only $.10/kWh, 1 MW is $100/hour.  Tell them the solution is to hire a experience industrial energy consultant, and that you will help minimize the cost of this by providing assistance.  That will get the job done and will allow you to learn something.

No, I'm not going to suggest anything that doesn't include a proper professional looking into things because anything else is irresponsible and will be more costly in the long run.

Comment: not strictly true. Alot of industrial machines using motors use induction motors. Replacing these with motor-drives (using BLAC) can provide energy savings, especially where slip control is used.

Comment: that's a project i need to work on as an intern, and i'm just looking for some guidance as in how to proceed with this sort of problem to be solved.

Comment: reducing their motors' energy consumption is something that has no relationship with the cost of energy they are consuming, because during the period in which they are producing, they rely on their own turbo generators, and after that they reconnect their electrical installation to their energy provider, so it's not a question of reducing costs, it's just a question of reducing energy consumption, which by the way will help keep the cables and the motors in better conditions and prevent decreasing their lifetime.

Comment: @JonRB if you're going to throw a VFD into the mix you've now got its efficiencies to take into account. AC induction motors are some of the most efficient electrical-to-mechanical devices we've ever invented. If you think you've got a slip problem you should probably not be using NEMA class D motors. Class A/B motors are the most common and typically have less than 5% slip.

Comment: afraid they are not, induction machines are quite bad. A VFD-motor pair can get up to 95% efficient (specific design point). You will not get that with an induction machine. http://www2.schneider-electric.com/documents/original-equipment-manufacturers/pdf/motion_control.pdf  Even across the range a sync machine driven with an inverter beats an induction machine. The reason Induction machines are everywhere is because they are cheap to make and they are robust and just work(tm)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is already some capacitor bank at all in this company...  If the company is trying to be cheap (hire an intern to do the job or a professional company), maybe they do not even know about power factor, proper wiring, balancing and such things.

You might try to make some simple measurement of the power factor on different devices (not easy), look for capacitor banks, etc.  Maybe, just maybe, that could help a lot.

On the other side, if every single motor there has full electronic drive with power factor correction... maybe it is not even an electrical problem at all, maybe 99.999999% mechanical (too much friction, old mechanisms, inefficient process).

Answer (score 0):

First I know next to nothing about big motors.

At some point the motors are doing work, and that is a fixed amount of energy.
(of course as Dave Tweed said, less friction etc. can reduce that loss.)
You are left with the efficiency of the motor.
So a more efficient motor for a load that is on most of the time.
For an intermittent load it might save to to have a motor that was only on when needed rather than a motor that was on all the time and engaged a clutch when needed.

Re capacitor banks:  I don't think they actually change the energy loss.  They make the energy cheaper because the power company charges for poor power factor.  Speculating wildly, the capacitor bank probably looses some energy.. I have no idea if it is a significant loss.